# Need assistance JAVA quicksort recursion

Tags: java, recursion

For school I have to write a quicksort for an Array of strings. I think my partition is good but I keep getting error with the recursion.

```
public static int partition(String[] input, int max) {
    // pivot is dividing point
    // I keeps track of lesser values
    // count is just a counter
    // Pivots in place
    int pivot = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int count = 1;

    while (count <= max) {
        if (input[count].compareTo(input[pivot]) < 0) {
            input[i] = input[count];
            i = i + 1;
        }
        if (count == max) {
            input[i] = input[pivot];
            input[pivot] = input[i];
        }
        count++;
    }
    return pivot;
}

public static void qSort(String[] input) {
    int index = partition(input, input.length - 1);
    int count = 0;
    if (count < index - 1) {
        partition(input, index - 1);
    }
    if (index + 1 < count && count < input.length) {
        partition(input, input.length - 1);
    }
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: `input[i]=input[count];` I expected to see values be swapped here. What happens to the value that was already in `input[i]`?

Comment: Hers a hint for you: the partition and qsort methods generally receive indices aside from the value array itself...

Comment: You want us to fix your syntax errors? Where did you even get the idea something like this was valid code: `qSort(input[])`. Also compare the parameter type your `partition` method needs with type of the value you pass to it.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I added input[count]=input[i]. That should help with that. I think my main problem is the butchering of the recursion. I'm trying to figure out how to limit all my successive recursions to only their respective subarrays,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation has a lot of mistakes. First of all, you're always choosing the pivot to be the element at index 0 of the array. The idea of quicksort is that you choose some pivot, partition the array around it, then recursively apply quicksort on both partitions around the chosen pivot. How do you identify the start and end of the partitions you'll call quicksort recursively on? You need to pass those as arguments to your partition method as others have mentioned in the comments, same thing for the quicksort method itself.

```
public void swap (String [] array, int i, int j) {
    String tmp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = tmp;
}

public static int partition (String [] array, int low, int high) {
    String pivot = array[low];
    int index = low+1;
    for (int i = low+1; i <= high; i++) {
        if (pivot.compareTo(array[i]) > 0) {
            swap(array, i, index);
            index++;
        }
    }
    swap(array, low, index-1);
    return index-1;
}

public static void qsort(String [] array, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
        int p = partition(array, low, high);
        qsort(array, low, p);
        qsort(array, p+1, high);
    }
}
```

Obviously this isn't the best way to choose the pivot as some arrays will make the algorithm perform very poorly. A better method would be to use a random pivot each time.

Comment: It's better than anything I could have came up with. I'm trying it out now and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It works. God Bless you man, I've been spinning my wheels for like 4 days. I also learned a lot from your answer, so next time i might be able to get it. Thanks again, I really appreciate it.